# select and input field, same formatting, different size

Tags: html, css

Why is it that `<input>` and `<select>` fields are displayed in different sizes, even if formatted in the same way?

```
.classname fieldset input,select {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

The `<select>` ends up a little smaller than `<input>`. - Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/2991/).
[image]

Comment: What browser, version, os, device?

Comment: add - box-sizing: border-box; for .classname fieldset input,select

Comment: FF 38.0.1 , IE 11.0.9600.17801 , Chrome is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying `box-sizing` and reseting `border` values:

```
.classname fieldset input,select 
{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #AAA; /* Set your color here. */
}
```

Comment: Strange, this helped a little but didn't solve the problem. Still one px difference.

Comment: Added padding: 1px; in additional to your code was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you likely want to set `box-sizing`, however it should be set to `border-box` and not `content-box`, meaning you should also not need to change anything else:

```
.classname fieldset input,select {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[**Box-Sizing:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> The box-sizing CSS property is used to alter the default CSS box model
>   used to calculate widths and heights of elements.
>
> **border-box**
>
> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but
>   not the margin.